# Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

After having converted this code from mysql to mysqli, there appears an error while executing through the login page with the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in dbc.php on line 127. Unfortunately I can't help myself to correct it....Any help would be highly appreciated.

dbc.php (given below)

```html
<?php


/******************** MAIN SETTINGS - PHP LOGIN SCRIPT V2.1 **********************
Please complete wherever marked xxxxxxxxx

/************* MYSQL DATABASE SETTINGS *****************
1. Specify Database name in $dbname
2. MySQL host (localhost or remotehost)
3. MySQL user name with ALL previleges assigned.
4. MySQL password

Note: If you use cpanel, the name will be like account_database
*************************************************************/

define ("DB_HOST", "89.46.111.48"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "Sql1120771"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","l226266154"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","Sql1120771_3"); // set database name

$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = $link->select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Registration Type (Automatic or Manual) 
 1 -> Automatic Registration (Users will receive activation code and they will be automatically approved after clicking activation link)
 0 -> Manual Approval (Users will not receive activation code and you will need to approve every user manually)
*/
$user_registration = 1;  // set 0 or 1

define("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 10); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password

//define ("ADMIN_NAME", "admin"); // sp

/* Specify user levels */
define ("ADMIN_LEVEL", 5);
define ("USER_LEVEL", 1);
define ("GUEST_LEVEL", 0);



/*************** reCAPTCHA KEYS****************/
$publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


/**** PAGE PROTECT CODE  ********************************
This code protects pages to only logged in users. If users have not logged in then it will redirect to login page.
If you want to add a new page and want to login protect, COPY this from this to END marker.
Remember this code must be placed on very top of any html or php page.
********************************************************/

function page_protect() {
session_start();

global $db; 

/* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        logout();
        exit;
    }
}

// before we allow sessions, we need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database

/* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
 if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
 /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */
 
 $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
 $rs_ctime = $link->query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die($link->error);
 list($ckey,$ctime) = $rs_ctime->fetch_row();
 // coookie expiry
 if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

  logout();
  }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.   
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

  if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
     session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.
 
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
  /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */ 
    list($user_level) = mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'")->fetch_row();

    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    
    } else {
    logout();
    }

  } else {
 header("Location: login.php");
 exit();
 }
}
}



function filter($data) {
 $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
 
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 
 $data = $link->real_escape_string($data);
 
 return $data;
}



function EncodeURL($url)
{
$new = strtolower(ereg_replace(' ','_',$url));
return($new);
}

function DecodeURL($url)
{
$new = ucwords(ereg_replace('_',' ',$url));
return($new);
}

function ChopStr($str, $len) 
{
    if (strlen($str) < $len)
        return $str;

    $str = substr($str,0,$len);
    if ($spc_pos = strrpos($str," "))
            $str = substr($str,0,$spc_pos);

    return $str . "...";
} 

function isEmail($email){
  return preg_match('/^\S+@[\w\d.-]{2,}\.[\w]{2,6}$/iU', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function isUserID($username)
{
 if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{5,20}$/i', $username)) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
 } 
 
function isURL($url) 
{
 if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i', $url)) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
} 

function checkPwd($x,$y) 
{
if(empty($x) || empty($y) ) { return false; }
if (strlen($x) < 4 || strlen($y) < 4) { return false; }

if (strcmp($x,$y) != 0) {
 return false;
 } 
return true;
}

function GenPwd($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; //no vowels
  
  $i = 0; 
    
  while ($i < $length) { 

    
    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
       
    
    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}

function GenKey($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
  
  $i = 0; 
    
  while ($i < $length) { 

    
    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
       
    
    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}


function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

$sess_user_id = strip_tags($link->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']));
$cook_user_id = strip_tags($link->real_escape_string($_COOKIE['user_id']));

if(isset($sess_user_id) || isset($cook_user_id)) {
$link->query("update `users` 
   set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
   where `id`='$sess_user_id' OR  `id` = '$cook_user_id'") or die($link->error);
}  

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

header("Location: login.php");
}

// Password and salt generation
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)     {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else     {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}

function checkAdmin() {

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}

}

?>
```

LOGIN PAGE

```html
<?php 

***********************************************************/
include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
 $get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['usr_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
    $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
      $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";
    
}

 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
   AND `banned` = '0'
   ") or die ($mysqli->error); 
$num = $result->num_rows;

  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 
 
 list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = $result->fetch_row();
 
 if(!$approved) {
 //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
 $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";
 
 //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
  //exit();
  }
  
  //check against salt
 if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
 if(empty($err)){   

     // this sets session and logs user in  
       session_start();
    session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

    // this sets variables in the session 
  $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
  $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
  $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  
  //update the timestamp and key for cookie
  $stamp = time();
  $ckey = GenKey();
  $mysqli->query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die($mysqli->error);
  
  //set a cookie 
  
    if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
      setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
      setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
      setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
       }
    header("Location: myaccount.php");
   }
  }
  else
  {
  //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
  $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
  //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
  }
 } else {
  $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
   }  
}
      
      

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Members Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logForm").validate();
  });
  </script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="main">
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td width="160" valign="top"><p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td width="732" valign="top"><p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h3 class="titlehdr">Login Users 
      </h3>  
   <p>
   <?php
   /******************** ERROR MESSAGES*************************************************
   This code is to show error messages 
   **************************************************************************/
   if(!empty($err))  {
    echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
   foreach ($err as $e) {
     echo "$e <br>";
     }
   echo "</div>"; 
    }
   /******************************* END ********************************/   
   ?></p>
      <form action="login.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm" >
        <table width="65%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" class="loginform">
          <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td width="28%">Username / Email</td>
            <td width="72%"><input name="usr_email" type="text" class="required" id="txtbox" size="25"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input name="pwd" type="password" class="required password" id="txtbox" size="25"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" id="remember" value="1">
                Remember me</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td colspan="2"> <div align="center"> 
                <p> 
                  <input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" value="Login">
                </p>
                <p><a href="register.php">Register Free</a><font color="#FF6600"> 
                  |</font> <a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password</a> <font color="#FF6600"> 
                  </font></p>
                <p><span style="font: normal 9px verdana">Powered by <a href="http://php-login-script.com">PHP 
                  Login Script v2.3</a></span></p>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div align="center"></div>
        <p align="center">&nbsp; </p>
      </form>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
      </td>
    <td width="196" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please stop using PHP 5. You should have upgraded long time ago.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Do not use functions like `filter()`. All they do is damage your data. This is an awful practice, which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$link` variable is not being passed into your functions, so you need to take a look at [variable scoping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). So you need to pass `$link` into your functions, e.g. `function filter($link, $data) {` and then calling it like `$cookie_user_id  = filter($link, $_COOKIE['user_id']);`. Same thing with the `logout()` function and any other functions using `$link`.

Comment: Since I am lost in somewhere....could anyone correct the code, please?

Comment: You need to change `function filter($data) {` to `function filter($link, $data) {` and `function logout()` to `function logout($link)`. Then in your login page you need to change `filter($value);` to `filter($link, value);` and anywhere you see `logout();` should be `logout($link);`

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
global $db;
```

in some of your database functions. But earlier in the code, you did this:

```
$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = $link->select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

`select_db()` [returns a boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php#refsect1-mysqli.select-db-returnvalues). `$link` is your database connection, not `$db`.

The `filter()` function uses `$link` but does not declare it as global or accept it as an argument. You should not use that function, though. You should be using prepared statements rather than escaping strings and using them directly in queries like this:

```
"select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'"
```

You can check out [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more information on that.